# how to run kubectl command in java

Tags: java, kubectl

I can run `kubectl get secret/rabbitmq-expressmode -n expressmode` in shell successfully.

However when I try to run it in java with either `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, the error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): the server rejected our request for an unknown reason
```

is thrown out.

What's the possible reason?

Comment: Could you please provide your OS name?

Comment: First googling gives me: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java, did you check it?

Answer (score 2):

Best approach would be to use [official java client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java).
[Installation](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/wiki/1.-Installation) is pretty easy, and [code examples](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/wiki/3.-Code-Examples) shows you how to use it.

---

If the official one does not meet your requirements, there are also community-maintained client libraries:

- [Java (OSGi)](https://bitbucket.org/amdatulabs/amdatu-kubernetes/src/master/)
- [Java (Fabric8, OSGi)](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client)
- [Java](https://github.com/manusa/yakc)

Comment: I know kubernetes-client/java could be one solution. what I don't understand is that why run shell commnad in java failed

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but resolved by programmatically creating bash file containing kubectl... command I was trying to execute directly.

For example, create bash file and put your kubectl command there (i.e.: some-file.sh). Then try then executing it in bash process running within your java code (bash some-file.sh).